# Javascript: how to append to a constructor's prototype, if that constructor is already defined on another object's prototype

Tags: javascript

If I wanted an API to allow for aggregation-like inheritance using closures and the module pattern, I've come up with something like this:

```
function Vehicle(category) {
    this.category = category;
    return {
        Car: this.Car
    };
};

Vehicle.prototype.Car = function(type) {
    this.wheels = [];
    this.type = type;
    return {
        type: this.type,
        wheels: this.wheels,
        addWheel: this.addWheel,
    };
};

Vehicle.prototype.Car.prototype.addWheel = function() {
    this.wheels.push('a wheel');
};

roadCars = new Vehicle('Road Cars');
roadCars.honda = new roadCars.Car('Honda');
roadCars.honda.addWheel();

console.log(roadCars.honda.wheels); // [ 'a wheel' ]
```

This provides the API that I want when dealing with creating sub objects. However this line:

```
Vehicle.prototype.Car.prototype.addWheel = function() {
    this.wheels.push('a wheel');
};
```

seems like it should be written differently. Ideally I would want to be able to append to the sub-constructor's prototype without specifying the entire prototype chain.

Also, are there any better ways to achieve the same API?

Comment: You should not call functions that return objects with `new`. If you want to use `new`, write constructors not factories.

Comment: You can't mix returning objects with using `this`.

Comment: I'm sure not sure what's your actual use case for this kind of structure, but a Car is a type of Vehicle so it should ideally extend the Vehicle class, not be a property of it.

Comment: Ah yes. So you wouldn't incapsulate a car class in a vehicle class. This is strictly for learning purposes, I don't yet have a use case for this

Comment: Although, would this not enforce an aggregation relationship? That may be desirable.. I see that the answer below shows how to split them and still maintain that aggregation relationship if wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not creating new function `Car`

```
function Vehicle(category) {
    this.category = category;
    return {
        Car: this.Car
    };
};

function Car(type) {
    this.wheels = [];
    this.type = type;
    return {
        type: this.type,
        wheels: this.wheels,
        addWheel: this.addWheel,
    };
};

Car.prototype.addWheel = function() {
    this.wheels.push('a wheel');
};

Vehicle.prototype.Car = Car

roadCars = new Vehicle('Road Cars');
roadCars.honda = new roadCars.Car('Honda');
roadCars.honda.addWheel();

console.log(roadCars.honda.wheels); // [ 'a wheel' ]
```

Comment: Thanks. It still seems a bit weird how you create the logical concept of classes outside of the actual classes themselves in Javascript